# You device does not support VoIP call recording

Tags: calls, 7.0-nougat, voip, audio-recording

I own a stock OnePlus 3 device which is on android 7.1.1. I've not changed anything in the device! Everything is stock. I recently install an app called CUBE Acr to record viber and messenger calls. But when I install the application it says

> Sorry but your device does not support VoIP apps call recording ( Skype, Whatspp, Etc ). This feature will be disabled. You can still record phone calls.

How can I turn on this feature from the device itself? is there anyting I should do to device settings in order to get that feature working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can change it by settings. If you see the [list of compatible devices](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HDrXSLJxrzEsK4Uc6x6ej0TYbc8BnZtc4eIGrPtOwq0) listed in the app description, you will find that your device *does not figure* . Only one plus one from your OEM is compatible

Also if you read app reviews, on other devices which are not compatible, developer says it's due to *hardware or firmware* incompatibility

Comment: Is there any other application which would be available to my device? to record VoIP calls.

Comment: @beeshyams is there any latest list of supported devices? It works on Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 but it isn't listed.

Comment: @vasik988 I am sorry, I am not aware. But I do recall reading some blog that said legal issues are the main hurdle not technical or compatibility. And a lot of Chinese devices aren't exactly famous for being sticklers for rules

Comment: @beeshyams do you mean, it's illegal to record VoIP? (Didn't really understand the sentence).

Comment: @vasik988 I don't recall the details but it is the bigger issue of recording calls and violation of privacy. VIOP is a small portion of recording